# Yii2 controller or configuration raise that only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to do something very simple a REST response using json format.

I created a simple model:

### Model

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Post extends ActiveRecord
{        
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */ 
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'posts';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'content'], 'required'], 
        ];
    }
}
```

And a simple controller:

### Controller

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class PostsController extends ActiveController
{       
    public $modelClass = "app\models\Post";
}

?>
```

It is the configuration of my **web.php** file:

```
  $config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'wcHYBrv4bXfLJYnWzrpJz_5vARaAeE9U',
            'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            //'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'posts',           
            ]
        ],
        Other attributes...
```

The most important part (I think so) is the **urlManager** configuration, maybe I am missing something but I don't know where is the error below.

### The error

When I execute a request with method GET, everything is Ok, but with any other method it fail. It is the error:

```
{
  "name": "Method Not Allowed",
  "message": "Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: GET, HEAD.",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 405,
  "type": "yii\web\MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
}
```

I want to get a simple response like this guy got in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hko3AZE5b9M) I just did the same configuration, step by step.

Thank you.

### UPDATE

There is more information, when I using Postman, I got this Headers result.

[image]

I don't understand why only `ALLOW -> GET, HEAD`

It is the Body result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'post'],
    ],
],
```

See [config](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#configuring-url-rules) and full list of available [requests](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html#trying-it-out) in official docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'author',
                'pluralize' => false
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Please describe your solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to do something like that, I have it a little different. Try to change class in urlManager  to "yii\rest\UrlRule"

Exemple (this code works for me ) :

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => [                         
                        'post']
                ]
            ],

        ]
```

Now try to acces to this url POST frontend.dev/basic/web/post whit Postman

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class PostsController extends ActiveController
{       
    public $modelClass = "app\models\Post";

//uncomment actions allowed
public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
//        unset($actions['create']);
//        unset($actions['update']);
//        unset($actions['delete']);
//        unset($actions['view']);
//        unset($actions['index']);
        return $actions;
    }

    //setup verb allowed
    protected function verbs()
    {
        return [
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
            'view' => ['GET'],
            'index' => ['GET'],
        ];
    }
}
```

or setup in config file

```
'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                    'controller' => ['post', 'user', 'etc', 'etc2'],
                    'pluralize' => false,
                    'extraPatterns' => [
                        'POST' => 'create', // 'xx' refers to 'actionXx'
                        'PUT {id}' => 'update',
                        'PATCH {id}' => 'update',
                        'DELETE {id}' => 'delete',
                        'GET {id}' => 'view',
                        'GET {count}' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
           ],
```